# Is it required to attach request.application in django-oauth-toolkit?

Tags: django, django-oauth

I have a separate resource and auth service and am trying to override the `OAuth2Validator` in [django-oauth-toolkit](https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/oauth2_validators.py#L373) to work with this setup.

In the original impl, `OAuth2Validator.validate_bearer_token` sets the `request.client` to the OAuth2 application - is this something internally required for the rest of the oauth-toolkit to function, or am I safe to not implement this if my service won't use Application? In my case I'm just validating the scopes/expiry/user of the token, and since Application is not stored on my resource, it is an extra request to retrieve it.